# Can you change separator width for different tableview cells?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I apologize in advance if the question has been asked before or the answer is obvious – I'm just having trouble finding a good answer to this question.

Is it possible to have different separator widths for different cells in a tableview? 
I want to have the first several cells have short separator widths and the last cell to have both the top and bottom separators go edge to edge.

Example image:

[image]

I am able to fake the desired look by setting the separator style to "none" in storyboard, then add a light gray UIView in each cell to be the separator (inside cellForRow method). However, I'd like to avoid this if possible.

Is there a better way to change the widths of the separator for different cells? 
Note: I am using Swift

Comment: Have you tried using `cell.separatorInset`? Probably the best place to do this is inside the `willDisplayCell` method and set the inset as desired for a specific `indexPath.row`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the dimensions of the separator using `cell.separatorInset`.

For instance this draws a shorter separator for the first three cells:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row < 3 {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 30, 0, 11) // shorter separator
    else {
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 3, 0, 11) // longer separator
    }
}
```

From the `willDisplayCell` docs:

> A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color. After the delegate returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame properties, and then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.

Comment: Thank you very much koen! Your solution works perfectly. May I ask – what is the reason you prefer to place this in willDisplay cell rather than in cellForRow?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I used a custom cell, separator line takes the whole width, but I want the default style, the shorter one, in which separator line is not showed under cell icon image. And I want it to be always aligned with my cell label leading position like iPhone's settings.

I wrote below code to achieve that effect in tableView cell file.

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let g = contentView
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            iconContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            iconContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            iconContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.heightAnchor, constant: -12),
            iconContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconContainer.widthAnchor),
            
            iconImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconContainer.centerXAnchor),
            iconImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconContainer.centerYAnchor),
            iconImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconContainer.widthAnchor, constant: -10),
            iconImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.widthAnchor),
            
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconContainer.trailingAnchor, constant: 20),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor)
        ])
        separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,
                                      left: 40 + iconContainer.frame.size.width,
                                      bottom: 0,
                                      right: 0)
    }
```